# Salvaging old Creative speakers

Tags: amplifier, audio, sound, speakers

I have some old Creative Inspire 6700 speakers with a dead amplifier. They are composed by four 8 RMS Watt speakers.

I'm I able to use two of those speakers with TPA3110 amplifier like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-X-8-Watt-6-Ohm-Class-D-Audio-Amplifier-Board-TPA3110-Mini-Stereo-Power-Amp-L3-/272226548195

I'm not sure if this is the correct community, so sorry if not.

Answer (score 1):

You did not actually ASK a question there. But if we assume that you are asking IF you can use those recycled Creative Inspire 6700 speakers with a TPA3110-based amplifier, then the answer is very likely yes. I don't see any basic problem there. The TPA3110 amplifier is likely better than the original amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you use two pairs in parallel or 4 Ohms a 12Vdc clean supply is required.

If you put in series, then use 18V (give or take 6V) to get more or less power.

A 19V Laptop charger would be fine or a PC HDD 12V out but may need an added Cap (low ESR type) for noise reduction depending on supply used.

Also it would be wise to use twisted pairs for DC power.

An unregulated 12V wall supply would not be a good choice due to 120/100Hz hum.